# how to effect bool in different script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean

I'm trying to have it so when I pick up an object, in this case a gun, it tags a bool, only problem is the gun pick up and the gun shoot scripts are two different scripts. So currently I'm trying to get the pickup script to effect the shoot script. I got it to change with the pickup script but can't get the pickup script to change the shoot script, here's the bit of code in question, any help would be greatly appreciated. If the full code of both scripts are needed id be happy to oblige, I just didn't want to force people to sort through 120 lines of code right off the bat.

```
public float damage = 10f;
public float range = 100f;
public float fireRate = 15f;
public float Impact = 40f;


public Camera fpsCam;
public bool pickedUp = false;
public ParticleSystem muzzleFlash;
public GameObject impactEffect;

private float nextTimeToFire = 0f;
private PickupScript myScript;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    if (gameObject.GetComponent<PickupScript>().pickedUp = true) ;
    setbool pickedUp = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Your if conditional lacks one "=", to be a comparison, not an asignment.

If that was a typo error, read further:

If I understood correctly, you only need to know that you can reference those scripts to each other.

Seems that you already know that cause you are using PickupScript as a variable, so I'll try to refresh the ways to reference that kind of stuff, so maybe it helps.

Scripts are classes, like `GameObject` is also a class. So when you make a GameObject variable public and assign from Editor the corresponding GameObject, you are stablishing a reference.

You could also do that finding on your game the script to reference, by TAG name for example.

In your case you got 2 classes, `PickUpScript` and `GunShot`.

If they are part of the same GameObject, you can assign them from Editor, if not, use [FindGameObjectsWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html). Once you have the reference in each script, you can assign the value bidirectionally.

```
public class PickupScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool pickUpBool = false;
    public Shotgun shotgun = false;

}

public class Shotgun : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool shotgunBool = false;
    public PickupScript pickupScript = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (gameObject.GetComponent<PickupScript>().pickUpBool == true)
        {
            shotgunBool = true;
        }
    }
}
```